# Is it possible to reset a class (specifically its animation) back to its initial state on click

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have an animation script that is supposed to change a `div`'s animation based upon mouse events (like mousemove, click, etc). One issue is that an animation is supposed to start every time you click the `div`.

In Chrome, the only browser available for testing *(read note at bottom), this does not work:

```
//The non-clicked class is "notClicked"
//The clicked class is "clicked"
//The will be referred to as elem
elem.onclick = function(){
  elem.className="notClicked";
  elem.className="clicked";
}
```

when the item is clicked once, it works as expected, but if it is clicked twice (two events fired) what happens is that:

- in element inspector, the class shows a change
- however, the animation continues as if the class never changed, and the second event never fired.

**NOTE:** I unfortunately only have a chromebook, and I can not do testing on other browser since I only have chrome. I know I am cheap. I am sorry.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:** native javascript is preferred, but jQuery solutions are not bad.

**MORE NOTES:** for clarity, as I think I have confused many people, when the object is clicked the second time, the animation is supposed to start over, not continue.

**JS FIDDLE (As requested):** [that fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4ueLprx/)

Comment: Within the same function you are changing the class name twice? Won't the element always have the class `clicked` because the second would overwrite the first? You are not even appending.

Comment: @Harry you misunderstood. the animation continues after the second event is fired, as if the second event never fired

Comment: can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @DaMaxContent: Nope, I don't think I misunderstood the question. I was just saying that the two changes happen within fraction of a second leading to the browser almost not noticing it at all. You would need to add a delay between the removal and re-addition (using timeout) like in my answer :)

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/o4ueLprx/1/

Comment: Nice one @Sammy. If you don't mind can I link your comment to my answer? The current animation in my answer was just a sample and is different to the one provided in OP's fiddle.

Comment: I was just about to add it myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a timeout between the removal of the class and its re-addition because otherwise the amount of time for which the class is absent is too miniscule for the browser to notice a difference.

Below is an example of what I mean. You would be able to see that everytime you click the element, it goes back to its original state and the animation restarts all over again.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('div');
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.className == '') { /* for the first click, add class immediately */
      this.className = 'animated';
    } else { /* for second and subequent clicks, first remove class and add after timeout */
      this.className = '';
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        el.className = 'animated';
      }, 100);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.animated {
  animation: zoom 2s linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  to {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div>Moving Div!</div>
```

---

**NOTE**: The animation used in the above snippet is only a sample for illustration. I had created it before seeing your fiddle. [Sammy has kindly contributed a fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976833/is-it-possible-to-reset-a-class-specifically-its-animation-back-to-its-initial/34976944#comment57683346_34976833) to fit the animation given in question. See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4ueLprx/1/).

Answer (score 1):

here is an example how you can escape second click.
in first click it makes a  `e.preventDefault();` son in second click you can check if it has been cliked by  `if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {` so you can escape 2. click

```
$add_table_form.on('submit', function (e) {
      if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        save_table();
      }
    });
```